# SharedPreferences PreferenceManager crash

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am new in developing in Java. I am making an app which uses SharedPreferences. The the specific tutorial I used is this: 

http://blog.donnfelker.com/2011/02/17/android-a-simple-eula-for-your-android-apps/ 

I have modified the code a bit, but it is giving me an error:

```
public class SimpleEula extends Application {
    private String EULA_PREFIX = "eula";
    public Activity mActivity;

    public SimpleEula(Activity context) {
        mActivity = context;
    }

    public void showEula() {
        SharedPreferences sh_showEula;
        final String eulaKey = EULA_PREFIX;
        final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mActivity);
        ...
```

I log my code after every line, and my app crashes at:

```
    final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mActivity);
```

Even if I change the line to:

```
    final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

I still get a crash. I don't know what the problem is. Could someone help me?

Thanks in advance



**EDIT:**

These are the errors in LogCat:

```
08-21 20:44:58.905: E/AndroidRuntime(610): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 20:44:58.905: E/AndroidRuntime(610): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.test/com.test.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 20:44:58.905: E/AndroidRuntime(610):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
08-21 20:44:58.905: E/AndroidRuntime(610):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
08-21 20:44:58.905: E/AndroidRuntime(610):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
08-21 20:44:58.905: E/AndroidRuntime(610):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
08-21 20:44:58.905: E/AndroidRuntime(610):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-21 20:44:58.905: E/AndroidRuntime(610):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-21 20:44:58.905: E/AndroidRuntime(610):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-21 20:44:58.905: E/AndroidRuntime(610):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 20:44:58.905: E/AndroidRuntime(610):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-21 20:44:58.905: E/AndroidRuntime(610):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-21 20:44:58.905: E/AndroidRuntime(610):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-21 20:44:58.905: E/AndroidRuntime(610):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-21 20:44:58.905: E/AndroidRuntime(610): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 20:44:58.905: E/AndroidRuntime(610):  at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(PreferenceManager.java:371)
08-21 20:44:58.905: E/AndroidRuntime(610):  at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:366)
08-21 20:44:58.905: E/AndroidRuntime(610):  at com.test.test.SimpleEula.show(SimpleEula.java:23)
08-21 20:44:58.905: E/AndroidRuntime(610):  at com.test.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
08-21 20:44:58.905: E/AndroidRuntime(610):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
08-21 20:44:58.905: E/AndroidRuntime(610):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
08-21 20:44:58.905: E/AndroidRuntime(610):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
08-21 20:44:58.905: E/AndroidRuntime(610):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: please could you post the error message? Should be visible in logcat

Comment: Are you sure, that you want to extend the Application class? I never used an Application subclass written by myself, so i don't know, why you are doing it, but you should try extending the Activity class, and see if you get the same error. Activities are also Contexts, so you can show Dialogs passing an Activity reference as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NullPointerExepter is caused by extending the Activity or Application class. This code works:

```
public class SimpleEula {

    private String EULA_PREFIX = "eula";
    private Activity mActivity;

    public SimpleEula(Activity context) {
        mActivity = context;
    }

    public void show() {
        final String eulaKey = EULA_PREFIX;
        final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mActivity);
            ...
```

Now it works. Thank you all for your help

Comment: Actually the context you are sending is coming inside your 'Application' extended class. You must register your Application class in your manifest, else the Application sub classes class will not be linked to the Run-time and hence the context will always be null ! which leads to NullPointerException, that is the cause of your exception !

Comment: you can following the answer in this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653918/nullpointerexception-in-android-app-on-sharedpreferences-declaration), which goes in a much generic sense by using a Base Context with the method getBaseContext().

Answer (score 0):

Better try using `getApplicationContext()` for Application class,

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.
                                   getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

What I do,

```
public class SimpleEula extends Application {
    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mContext = this; // use this mContext
    }

    public void showEula() {
          SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.
                                   getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for the quick answer. But the new technique does not work either. I get the same crash.

Comment: have you declared Application class in Manifest file?